# Infowindow de google maps repite la información de las ventanas en todos los marcadores

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Tengo este codigo que crea markers en la api de google maps, estas van con su infowindow las cuales se obtienen de una base de datos

```
   
    const locationss = [
       <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?> 
    [<?php echo $row['coordenadas']; ?>, '<?php echo $row['texto']; ?>'],
          <?php } ?>
  ]; 

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  
  
  for (var location of locationss) {
  
     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0],location[1]),
           map: map,
           icon: image,
      });
      
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        infoWindow.setContent(location[2]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
  }
  }
```

Los marcadores se muestran  bien el problema surge al desplegar las ventanas con los textos ya que en todos los marcadores solo muestra la ultima información que encuentra en el array.
En la consola del navegador muestra que el recorrido se hace correctamente.[imagen de consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu4sj.jpg)

Que tengo que hacer para que muestre los contenidos de las ventanas correctamente ?
Ayudaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

un poco tarde pero espero que esto ayude a muchos que tienen el mismo problema.

Lo que pasa es que estas poniendo en información lo que hay en `location[2]` es por eso que se repite la información y al dar click en cualquier marcador, le dices que te abra la ventana de información pero del ultimo `marker` que hay cuando termina tu ciclo FOR.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        infoWindow.setContent(location[2]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
```

Para que no te muestre siempre la misma información cuando abra la ventana en diferente marcador, declara una variable dentro del FOR y mete en ella lo que quieres que muestre en la ventana al abrirse, así estará disponible en cada uno de los marcadores y podrás visualizar la información de cada una, también mete tu variable `infoWindow` algo como esto

```
for (var location of locationss) {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infoConten = $arreglodeinfo.Texto1[x] //texto a mostrar del arreglo, de la columna Texto1 en el indice [x] que va autoincrementando
```

Creamos un nuevo campo en tu google.maps.Marker llamado `ventana` al cual le vamos a dar el valor de nuestra variable en donde hemos guardado lo que queremos que muestre de información

```
     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0],location[1]),
           map: map,
           icon: image,
           ventana: infoConten
```

Ahora para que cada marcador abra su propia ventana de información, intenta diciendo que abra la ventana pero de ese elemento con `this.ventana` para ver la información de ese elemento  y `this` para abrir la ventana de ese elemento.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.setContent(this.ventana);
  infoWindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Ahora juntando todo el código, debería de quedar algo así:

```
      const locationss = [
        <?php while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>[<?php echo $row['coordenadas']; ?>, '<?php echo $row['texto']; ?>'],
        <?php } ?>
      ]

      for (var location of locationss) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infoConten = $arreglodeinfo.Texto1[x] //texto a mostrar del arreglo, de la columna Texto1 en el indice [x] que va autoincrementando

        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[0], location[1]),
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          ventana: infoConten
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infoWindow.setContent(this.ventana);
          infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
```

Espero haber ayudado a alguien con esta información.